# Calling PHP function doesn't work in index.php

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, page-template, callbacks

I have a function I wrote in my functions.php page for a gallery to display on certain pages. It displays on custom templates, but now I need it to display on index.php Here is the code from my functions.php file:

```
if ( 'templates/awards.php' == $template ||  'templates/events.php' == $template ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'id'         => 'imageupload',
        'post_types' => array( 'page', $post_type),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'title'  => __( 'Image Gallery', 'min' ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => __( 'Show', 'min' ),
                'id'    => "{$prefix}_gallery-show",
                'desc'  => __( '', 'meta-box' ),
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'clone' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'id'               => "{$prefix}_image_advanced",
                'name'             => __( 'Image Advanced', 'min' ),
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                // Delete image from Media Library when remove it from post meta?
                // Note: it might affect other posts if you use same image for multiple posts
                'force_delete'     => false,
                // Maximum image uploads
                //'max_file_uploads' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

if ( 'index.php' == $template ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'id'         => 'imageupload',
        'post_types' => array( 'page', $post_type),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'title'  => __( 'Image Gallery', 'min' ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => __( 'Show', 'min' ),
                'id'    => "{$prefix}_gallery-show",
                'desc'  => __( '', 'meta-box' ),
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'clone' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'id'               => "{$prefix}_image_advanced",
                'name'             => __( 'Image Advanced', 'min' ),
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                // Delete image from Media Library when remove it from post meta?
                // Note: it might affect other posts if you use same image for multiple posts
                'force_delete'     => false,
                // Maximum image uploads
                //'max_file_uploads' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    );
}







          function min_get_page_gallery( $echo = true) {
           global $post;
           $show_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_gallery-show',  true);

            if ( empty($show_gallery) ) {
       return;
       }

             $gallery      = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_image_advanced', false);

             ob_start();
       ?>
       <div class="gallery" id="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
            <button class="gallery-move-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"     aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <div class="image_container clearfix">

       <?php
        $count = count($gallery);
        $num = ceil($count / 3);

        echo '<div class="gallery_inner">';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) {

                echo '<div class="row'. (0 == $i ? ' active': ' inactive') .'">';
            }
            echo '<div class="col-sm-4 img_container' . (0 == $i ? ' active': ' inactive') . '">';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($gallery[$i], 'thumb-gallery');
            echo '</div>';
            if ( $i % 3 == 2  || ($i+1) == $count) {
                echo '</div>';
            }

        }
        echo '</div>';
    ?>
    </div>
    <button class="gallery-move-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
   <?php
       $return = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();

           if ( $echo ) {
           echo $return;
       } else {
           return $return;
  }

}
```

That code works like a charm on other page templates, such as awards.php . Here is where I call it as min_get_page_gallery(); in awards.php where it works flawlessly:

```
   <?php
       /* Template Name: Awards Page Template */

       get_header(); ?>

   <div class="container" id="block-no-sidebar">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div id="award-list">
        <?php echo min_get_awards(); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
        <?php min_get_page_gallery(); ?>
   </div>
        <?php min_get_page_tabs(); ?>
   </div>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now finally, I try to add the same function call of min_get_page_gallery(); in my index.php file like this:

```
    <?php
        // Silence is golden.
        if ( ! defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
       exit;
       }
    ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <style class="take-to-head">
           #block-main-content-with-sidebar { background: #ffffff; }
        </style>

    <div class="container" id="block-main-content-with-sidebar">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <?php
              if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                   l('block-' . get_post_type());
              endwhile; else:
                   l('block-none' );
              endif;

           ?>

         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <?php l('block-sidebar'); ?>
         </div>   
      </div>
   <div class="row">
      <?php min_get_page_gallery(); ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Is there something I'm missing??

Comment: Is the beginning of the code missing from the question?

Comment: No I took the chunk of code from functions.php that initiates the function for the gallery

Comment: Have a look at the top of your question.  There seems to be a code fragment within a sentence and your function doesn't begin `function `.

Comment: Yes I just saw that someone made an suggested edit and it went through. It should be good now

Comment: Starting with the obvious things to tick off...  Is the min_gallery-show custom field truthy on the page you're testing?  Is there a problem with whitespace at the start of index.php?

Comment: it's not even showing in screen options to check off the image gallery custom field, like it is for the awards page. I'm going to add the custom fields code in the top

Comment: Well, if you can't check it off in the admin then the field isn't set and so your function returns when the `if ( empty($show_gallery) ) { return;  }` line runs.

Comment: I thought I did set it. if You check the updated code, it should show at the top as if ('index.php') == $template

Comment: But I don't see where `$template` is set and also setting an array `$meta` (outside your function's scope) doesn't save a meta value to the database.

Comment: Ahhh let me add that part in so you can see it. I was trying to get only the relevant parts of functions.php for this

Comment: It's good to have a reduced case, but I wasn't sure if the problem was unassigned variables.

Comment: this is where $template is defined:  `$template = get_page_template_slug( $post_id );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the function `get_page_template_slug`

When you call `$template = get_page_template_slug( $post_id );` it won't return `index.php` if you are using the default theme template.  It only works when viewing Pages and will either return the slug of the Custom Page Template assigned to that Page or an empty string otherwise.

So `if ( 'index.php' == $template )` will always be false.

Rather than trying to detect which template file is running, use WP's is_ functions.

```
true == is_front_page()
```

on your site's home page, for example.

There is a whole range of these functions to check the sort of page you are on. Have a read up on them in the documentation available online. If really feel the need to check whether you are using the index.php template then you could set a global flag variable at the start of that template and check it within your function, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks so how would I get it to call the default template as well? or would I have to assign another variable to index.php?

Comment: @MikeL5799 see my addition to the answer.

Comment: I don't think is_front_page is going to work, being that this page just uses index.php, but isn't the front page.

Comment: I did say "for example." I've added some elaboration.

Comment: Thanks so much so I did this: `if ( is_page(35393) == true )`  or should I have true first?

Comment: Cool. It works either way around. True first is a good habit that stops hard to trace errors if you mistakenly use just a single = sign.

Comment: It's still not working. i have no idea why? lol do I have to do anything with the function for the gallery itself?

Comment: I even tried combining it with the ones that work like this: `if ( 'templates/awards.php' == $template ||  'templates/events.php' == $template || ( is_page(35393) == true )) `

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Have you debugged whether your meta flag is set?

Comment: No how do I do that? lol

Comment: I'll expand my answer to help. I need to see the whole index.php file as I can't tell what your code is doing exactly. Might not have time till weekend.

Comment: That is the entire index.php file. The last chunk of code that has the comment Silence is Golden

Comment: How long is functions.php?

Comment: functions.php is 1400 lines long

Comment: I solved it!!! yes!!!!

Comment: Hey, cool. Well done. I was worrying it might be very hard to help further.

Comment: I thank you so much. After a few white screens of death, I got it lol.

Comment: Ok so the meta boxes are now showing but it's not displaying on the page now grrrrrrrrr

Comment: Nevermind fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to do some tweaking to get the meta to show in functions.php I added these lines: 
    `$pagemain = is_page();`

and then:

```
 if ( $pagemain == is_page( 35393 )  ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'id'         => 'imageupload',
        'post_types' => array( 'page'),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'title'  => __( 'Image Gallery', 'min' ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => __( 'Show', 'min' ),
                'id'    => "{$prefix}_gallery-show",
                'desc'  => __( '', 'meta-box' ),
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'clone' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'id'               => "{$prefix}_image_advanced",
                'name'             => __( 'Image Advanced', 'min' ),
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                // Delete image from Media Library when remove it from post meta?
                // Note: it might affect other posts if you use same image for multiple posts
                'force_delete'     => false,
                // Maximum image uploads
                //'max_file_uploads' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```